# The fastest way of reading grayscale image from HDD

Tags: c++, image, opencv, cuda

I am working with Image-Processing on GPU(CUDA). Input for CUDA kernel is two grayscale 8-bit images (`.tif`). They must be in GPU RAM memory as 1D arrays (0-based, row-major storage). The processing time is about 24ms, so the speed of reading is important for me.  In order to do that, first I need to read Image from HDD to CPU RAM memory(into 1d array of floats) and then use `cudamemcpy` to copy it into GPU RAM. What is the fastest way to read from HDD with c++?

My Images are 8-bit grayscale 1200x1600 (size 1.92 mb). I wrote test programs, which read about 250 images and measure a time:

With matlab (`imread`) the time for reading 1 image is `5.8ms`. This corresponds to `~300 Mb/s` and is close to peak bandwidth of my HDD.

But, as long as I work with CUDA, I need to use C++. I installed `OpenCV`. Unfortunately, I cannot read image directly into array of floats with OpenCV. After reading it into array of `uchar`, I convert my data into array of floats:

```
image = imread(b, 0);
image.convertTo(img_float, CV_32F);
float *d = img_float.ptr<float>(0);
```

After testing this implementation, I got worse result: `8.8ms` per image. Without convertion it was `8.2 ms`. Usually `c++` is faster, then Matlab. Is it possible to achieve peak bandwidth with c++, as I did with Matlab?

P.S. In c++ I used `release x64` mode with full optimization. Time for reading 250 different images was measured by function `clock()` in `c++` and `tic-toc` in matlab (and was divided over 250 to find time per 1 image).

Thanks

Comment: ***This corresponds to ~300 Mb/s and is close to peak bandwidth of my HDD.*** That is over the peak bandwith of a hard drive but reasonable for a SSD. SATA Hard drives top out at around 200 MB/s.

Comment: Yes, I have SSD. I tested it with independent software test

Comment: And please try whether image = imread(b, -1); is faster (to load image without change)

Comment: Mind that clock() measures cpu-time while tic-toc seems to measure wall-time, so if cv::imread and .convertTo is multi-threaded you give it a disadvantage in your measurement!

Comment: ok... tested `loaded image as is` (2nd param = -1) which didnt make any difference. and tested wall-time vs. cpu-time for `cv::imread` which made no difference either. Do you use `debug` or `release` libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested with (2nd param =-1), it is even a little bit slower(basically no difference). I use release libraries, also when I tried to use debug openCV libs in release mode, there was a error.

Comment: And I don't know what is wall time( Can this be an explanation why c++ is seems to be slower?

Comment: Not in my test... probably it's the internally used tiff library that's slower than matlab, as mikhail maltsev guesses but no guarantee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to look at. First: try to verify that your benchmark is really correct. Can file system caching affect the result? If yes, try to use larger datasize. Does your benchmark measure what you really intend to measure (i.e., does MatLab really convert images to float)? Are images read correctly without errors?

The straightforward answer to your question "What is the fastest way to read from HDD with c++?" is probably "C++ has (almost) no impact on speed of data transfer from HDD to RAM". Allocate the required amount of memory and use the native API of your OS to read the file: you'll get the maximum.

What could perhaps matter is the TIFF image processing library. Try to find out, what library OpenCV uses to handle TIFF. Does it perform any unnecessary conversions into some intermediate representation or just reads the blob of bytes? If the former is true, try to find another library or even parse the TIFF image manually (if it is not compressed, parsing TIFF is not a big deal). Conversion to float is probably not the bottleneck. OpenCV is able to use multithreading (verify that all CPU cores are utilized) and vectorization (you may check that, perhaps by looking at the actual code that performs conversion). Also, if you need to perform those operations repeatedly, avoid allocating and deallocating memory in a loop: do not perform conversion "in-place", but rather use two separate arrays (one for 8-bit image, one for floating-point).

P.S. Isn't it possible to convert the image in the GPU?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I checked that images are correctly loaded into RAM.  Yes, in Matlab you can read image into preallocated array of whatever type you want and conversion  will be done automatically. I will try to try read it by myself now. I didn't find the functions or libraries that can load image from SSD to GPU RAM directly.